# cronjob cannot find environment variables defined in .bashrc

Tags: cron, environment-variables, bashrc

I have a very simple requirement which i tried looking for solution but couldn't get any standard defined solution . what i want to know is for my question below what is the `correct` solution.

***Question***: i am required to run a cronjob ( which is a python script ) using crontab.

using crontab -e i added this line to my cron file:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/python /srv/x/y/src/run.py > /tmp/listener.log 2>&1
```

the script starts but it is using environment variables inside. **i get an error in log file that the env vars are not defined?**

where should i define my env vras? i even tried to define in `.bashrc` but still the same error. cronjob cannot find it.

what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a small bash script `mypythonscript` consisting of:

```
#!/bin/bash
set ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_1=...
set ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_2=...
/usr/bin/python /srv/x/y/src/run.py > /tmp/listener.log 2>&1
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod +x mypythonscript
```

In the crontab replace the line by

```
* * * * * /path/to/mypythonscript
```

Comment: If you're running bash, I think you want to use [`export VAR=value`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html) to have the variables actually passed to the environments of the commands you run. The [`set` builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html) assigns values to the positional parameters (among other things). Try `set x=blah; printf "x: $x\n1: $1\n"`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than keeping the variable definitions in two places, wrap your program call in a simple `bash` script that sources your `~/.bashrc`:

```
#!/bin/bash
source $HOME/.bashrc
/usr/bin/python /srv/x/y/src/run.py > /tmp/listener.log 2>&1
```

`chmod +x` the script, and run it from your `crontab`.