# Copy to Amazon S3 is not successful when running from cron

Tags: command-line, cron, amazon

I have shell script executed by cron.

```
*/5 * * * * /home/foo/backups/backup.sh
```

An backup script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE_NAME=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M)
PATH1="/home/foo/backups/data-$FILE_NAME.sql.gz"

pg_dump -U XXX -E utf8 --no-acl -h localhost --no-owner XXX | gzip -c > $PATH1
aws s3 cp $PATH1 s3://XXX
```

Cron is executed correctly and local backup is created. But dump file is not copied to Amazon S3 bucket. When I run `/home/foo/backups/backup.sh` manually, file is transfered to S3.

Is there any reason why S3 cli could not work when `aws s3 cp` is executed from cron?

Comment: I don't know anything about `aws`, but I know that `cron` does not have all the path environment. Try adding the path to the `aws` command in the script and see if works. If `aws` calls `cp` you may need to add the path to `cp` as well. This is just a guess.

Comment: @user68186 Adding full path to `aws` helped, you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Path and Other Environment Variables are not in `cron`

`cron` does not have many environment variables set. The default value of the `path` variable in `cron` is just `/usr/bin:/bin`. Try adding the full `/path/to/the/aws` command in the script.

See this answer for a different solution: [cronjob cannot find environment variables defined in .bashrc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/906286/cronjob-cannot-find-environment-variables-defined-in-bashrc)

Also see [Crontab execution of multiple commands but last command is omitted](https://askubuntu.com/a/936165/178692)

Hope this helps